# Can i increase the disc size while kafka is running?

Tags: apache-kafka

I've an Apache Kafka 2.7 and it is in the production environment, there are discs that we use as data storage, and they are %90 filled, how can i increase the disc capacity, they are in virtual environment would you also share the answer for if physical discs were connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've configured `log.dirs` to use specific volume mounts, then no.

The contents of the directories for that value must be topic-partition folders, not a parent folder of all volumes where it would be more possible to dynamically add directories.

Drives may be hot swappable on the physical server (or VM), yes, but you'll still need to edit the Kafka property file to include the new mount path, and restart the broker.

Also, if you add new disks, Kafka will not rebalance existing data, meaning you'll still have discs that are 90% full. In any environment, you'd need to create/acquire a new, larger disc, shutdown the machine, replicate the disc, then attach the new one, and restart.

Comment: I got you answer but i asked what if, we increase the existing disc of brokers.

Comment: And how do you plan on doing that while data may actively be written to the original disc?

Comment: The real solution for adding storage to Kafka without downtime is to add more brokers, then rebalance the topics across the cluster rather than within one/few brokers

Comment: Thanks, i guess that's a great way to do.

Comment: what if we take the risk of a downtime?

Comment: If you have at least 3 brokers, then only upgrade one at a time, there should be minimal downtime.